# In React, try to show different images according to the IDs passed to url

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, jsx

The robot images on the web page should be different depending on the robot id passed into the url but the web page shows all the same robot image. The following shows the part of the React JS codes.

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = ({name, email, id}) => {
return (
    <div className='tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5'>
        <img alt='robots' src={'https://robohash.org/${id}&200x200'} />
        <div>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <p>{email}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default Card;
```

Obviously the problem occurs at src={'https://robohash.org/${id}&200x200'}. Please help how to set the src part. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a back tick here not single quote.
Check by changing single quote to back tick ` and then see if src is formed correctly

```
<img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}&200x200`} />
```

Comment: Great, it worked!  That back tick solved the annoying problem. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I was learning react from a udemy course and came across this error too. Imagine spending over an hour trying to find the bug and it turns out to be this fix :|